# Upload permission modx

Tags: php, html, modx

I have a site on modx. I'm trying to implement uploading files from a website page to a server directory. I get a 403 Forbidden error when uploading. I already set the rights to the directory 777 755 but it did not help. I'm attaching the chunk and snippet code.

Text error: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.

I exposed the rights, but it did not help.

```
Snippet
<?php
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $targetDir = "image/";
    $targetFile = $targetDir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($targetFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    if ($uploadOk == 1) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $targetFile)) {
            echo "Файл успешно загружен.";
        } else {
            echo "Произошла ошибка при загрузке файла.";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Произошла ошибка при загрузке файла.";
}
```

Chunk

```
<form class="uploadfile" action="[[!uploadFilePDF]]" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Загрузить" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You're trying to get the pathinfo for a file that doesn't exist yet.  You can remove this line since you're not using the output anyway: `$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($targetFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));`

Comment: @BramVerstraten unfortunately it did not help me, error 403

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="uploadfile" action="[[!uploadFilePDF]]"
```

What is inside `action` finally? This should be page URL(where your snippet should be executed)  but not snippet call inself, is this something wrong here?
Is this `uploadFilePDF` your snippet provided above?

Comment: yes, that's right, the link leads to the snippet above

Comment: I am trying to call the $_FILES variable via var_dump. The server returns an empty array.

Comment: Strange, something like this should work: ```<form action="your_script.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" >
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>``` Also please double check you have nothing (snippets, plugins etc) what erase/can influence system array like $_FILES